# customizing drop down menu

Tags: html, css

Here is the drop down menu I am working on.

```
<select id="frames" onchange="updateDisplay()" class="styled-select">    
    <OPTION value="ravi">ravi</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="steve">steve</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="robert">robert</OPTION>

</select>​
```

and the css

```
select {
background-color:#232323;
    border-color:#232323;
    border-width:1px;
    color:white;
};​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi007/ZWwgW/3/

I am trying to add a grey back ground to drop down menu. I am partly successful.

I failed to add grey color to small button with arrow. I also want to make that arrow to white.

I am seeing a default yellow border around drop down when I click. Is there a way to make it blue

When googled I noticed that button part is related to browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the background to the LI elements as well. This is only an issue in certain browsers IIRC.

```
select, select > option {
    background-color:#232323;
    border-color:#232323;
    border-width:1px;
    color:white;    
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ZWwgW/4/)

As for the 'border' colour - are you sure this is not the 'outline'?? have you tried changing `outline-color: blue;` ? [Demo with outline.](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ZWwgW/5/)

Here is the difference with the LI's getting the background color in Chrome on Linux (Ubuntu) http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ZWwgW/7/
[image]

Comment: outline-color is what i am looking for. Thanks. Regarding adding the grey color to small box with arrow, and making the arrow white, I dont see any difference in your demo even after adding background to list elements.

Comment: makes a difference on my browser. I'll add a screenie. Like I said this is browser specific.

Comment: Thanks.hmmm unfortunately it is not working on windows chrome. :( . What about the little arrow. Is there a option to turn it to white.

Comment: not that I am aware of. But like people keep suggesting, the best solution here to ensure 100% cross browser compatibility and consistency would be to mask the control with a custom dropdown (select) menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the arrow but you can make it look like its changed with an Image.

Here is a simple trick, Have a look at this [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Z5ag/)

Not Exactly what you want, but helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly,
you won't be able to change that arrow with CSS, because it is rendered by the browser you are using.
The only thing I can think of is to use [this JQuery Library](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) ([example](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html))

And for the border I think you will be able to access it like this (this border is only rendered by some browsers like safari):

```
select::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

and if you are talking about the outline, you can simply do:

```
select{
outline-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: IIRC the 'yellow' he is talking about is not a border, but in fact an `outline`.